# Can't get spellcheck to work in any program?

Tags: spell-checking

I have noticed that spellcheck will work with any program on Ubuntu. For some reason, this stopped working when I purged OpenOffice and replaced it with LibreOffice. I am guessing that I failed to install back a package that provides this spellcheck.

All of thee misstakes inn thiss sentencee were NoT caughht.

Spell check is vital to me because I am a student and I can not hand in work with mispellings.

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to install the `aspell` package. It's the default Spell Checking software used by most Ubuntu Applications. You may also need to install additional libraries for whichever language you wish to use.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the language-support-en package apparently. took me a bit to find this fix. Thanks for all of the help :)

Comment: were you missing it bcuz you spelled it incorrectly? haha jk

Answer (score 0):

If you set your document language or system language to one that is not supported by the spell checker. For example English (New Zealand) you will not get spell check. Instead you would need to select English (UK).

The languages that are supported by the spell checker will have a special icon next to them in the drop down box.